# Load template inside a parent template

Tags: templates, redirect, child-theme, wp-redirect

Inside of my current theme directory, I created a folder called "mobile" which contains a separate set of template files, all optimized for mobile.

Now, say I setup a function that detects a mobile device, I would like wordpress to now load "mytheme/mobile/header.php" Instead of the themes root header.php and index files.

Is there some way I can tell wordpress to look in a template subfolder for the template files?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( condition ) 
{
    get_template_part( 'path/to/template', 'mobile' );
}
else
{
    get_template_part( 'template', 'mobile' ); // in rootpath
}
```

You can also intercept the behavior for `get_template_part()` with an action hook:

```
// Source in get_template_part
do_action( "get_template_part_{$slug}", $slug, $name );

function wpse21352_template_part_cb( $slug, $name )
{
    switch ( $name ) 
    {
        case 'mobile' :
            $slug = 'mobile/'.$slug;
            break;

        case 'tablet' :
            $slug = 'tablet/'.$slug;
            break;
    }
    return $slug;
}

// Now attach the above function to get_template_part()
function wpse21352_template_actions()
{
    $wpse21352_mobile_files = array(
         'header'
        ,'logo'
        ,'content'
        // ,'etc...'
    );

    foreach ( $wpse21352_mobile_files as $slug )
        add_action( 'wpse21352_template_part_cb', 'get_template_part_'.$slug, 10, 2 );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse21352_template_actions' ); // maybe some other hook
```

---

**EDIT:** As to @Otto comment, `locate_template()` might be a better choice for subdirectories. Please read the comments.

Comment: You should use `locate_template()` here, rather than `get_template_part()`; the former is intended to handle subdirectories, but the latter really isn't.

Comment: @Chip can you show me a quick example on how I can load all template files from a subfolder? I understand the concept but I cant seem to apply it right. Thanks

Comment: @Chip Bennet It works the way I wrote, but using the more native fn will work too.

Comment: @kaiser it *does* work, but it's not *intended* to be used for including from subdirectories. Thus, using it in this way could possibly introduce *unintended consequences*.

Comment: @levi I would recommend *not putting template-part files in subdirectories*. A better approach might be to suffix template-part files with `-mobile`, and then targeting that context (as @Kaiser demonstrates in his example code).

Comment: @Chip Bennet "_unintended consequences_" ... you're talking 'bout later wp versions which might change the way the path is set? Even if you take `load_template()` then the path will be relative to somewhere and it will likely be relative to a themes root dir, so I'd not say that the possibility of "_unintended consequences_" is high. Plus: Core changes behavior only in some rare cases and often leaves old inputs valid for some versions.

Comment: @Chip Bennet Maybe you want to fiddle with the code above? I edited the A. Feel free to add/modify the code.

Comment: @kaiser let me play around with an idea, and then I'll add something to your answer. I want to play around with taking advantage of passing an array to `locate_template()`.

Comment: @Chip Bennet Sounds good. I'm curious...

Comment: Basically, locate_template is designed to take a relative path as the first argument. Therefore it explicitly works with paths. get_template_part, on the other hand, is meant to take two "words" or "slugs" if you prefer, and to build the template path from them. So the fact that it works with subdirectories is more of a side effect instead of intended design. Future adjustments might break it if you try using subdirectories with it, but that won't happen with locate_template. Please use locate_template instead.

Comment: @Otto I always invite everyone to modify my Q/A. Please update it. Thanks!