# Is it possible to override the result of get_template_part()?

Tags: templates, child-theme, get-template-part

I'm working on a child theme, I strongly prefer not to override the main template files in order to maintain simplicity of the child theme as well as minimize the amount of code and maintenance over time.

In the loop, the index.php template in parent theme uses:
`get_template_part( 'content' );`

which will bring in *content.php*, I'm looking to have it behave more like `get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );` or similar in order to bring in different templates such as *content-aside.php*, etc, without creating an *index.php* in the child theme to overwrite the parent for a single line change.

`get_template_part()` consists of:

```
function get_template_part( $slug, $name = null ) {

    do_action( "get_template_part_{$slug}", $slug, $name );
    $templates = array();
    $name = (string) $name;
    if ( '' !== $name )
        $templates[] = "{$slug}-{$name}.php";

    $templates[] = "{$slug}.php";
    locate_template($templates, true, false);
}
```

So there's an action available, in my case called `get_template_part_content`

I can hook onto the action with something like:

```
add_action( 'get_template_part_content', 'child_post_styles', 10, 2 );

function child_post_styles ( $slug, $name ) {
    if( false == $name ){
        $name = get_post_format();
        $templates = array();
        if ( '' !== $name )
            $templates[] = "{$slug}-{$name}.php";

        $templates[] = "{$slug}.php";
        locate_template($templates, true, false);
    }
}
```

This obviously results in post duplication, one from my hooked function, which can display the desired template, and the other from the normal `locate_template` call in `get_template_part()`

I'm having trouble finding a way to accomplish this without duplication, or without ending page render right after serving my template part by doing something stupid such as a `break` or `exit`

Comment: Check [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/21325/31545)

Comment: Welcome to miserable life without template inheritance. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no hook to do this. Copy the index.php to the child theme and make the single line change. Also, tell the parent theme's author that they should make the same change in their theme, for flexibility.

Comment: This is false now, see @t-toudua answer here

Comment: His answer is not a solution, because the template part still loads and includes. The action hook cannot override that.

Comment: True, but you could use `ob_start` inside it and the `ob_end` at some later hook so its executed but never echoed, which usually is good enough. Or  you could use exit() to force terminate PHP (after you manually add everything still missing: footer, etc)

Comment: And that is still not a solution. Suppressing output is not the same as overriding things.

Comment: Exiting doesn't suppress output; it effectively stops execution at that point.

Comment: Yeah i can't believe there isn't any kind of filter in core to handle this, seems to be basic stuff if you want to be able to prevent the output.  I like @IvanCastellanos idea about ob_start/ob_end the only problem is you would have to trigger that on a hook fired AFTER the include, which there isn't any standard ones called after the the include that i can find

Answer (score 6):

I think it's not exactly possible the way you want to achieve. It's really annoying to not getting a filter there to alter template files names :(

I have a workaround on it though. Let use `content.php` for the comparison.

```
// content.php file 
$format = get_post_format();
if( '' != $format ){
    get_template_part( 'content-'. $format );
}
else{
    get_template_part( 'content-default' );
}
```

I haven't used the second argument of `get_template_part` function, rather i passed suffix on the first argument to avoid infinitive calls on `content.php` file if there's no `'content-'. $format` file.

Comment: I think this is a good way to do that. Not sure why it's not accepted :)

Comment: Reputation matters, maybe :)

Comment: Sorry @Shazzad, I gave your answer an upvote though as it is very clever :) If I could accept two, I would.

Answer (score 3):

Well, there is **SOLUTION**:

```
add_action('init', function(){ remove_all_actions('get_template_part_content'); });
add_action('get_template_part_content', 'yourFunc', 99, 2 );
function yourFunc ( $slug, $name ) {

    .........any codes here.............
    if ($name == 'header'){
       //but this will be executed before loading template... At this moment, Wordpress doesnt support any hooks for before/after LOAD_TEMPLATE...
    }
}
```

but think carefully, in which hook you should insert that action...
to manually get location, use, i.e. `locate_template('content-header.php', false);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pull in a file called content-aside.php you call the function like this:

```
get_template_part( 'content', 'aside' );
```

The second parameter is the name of the filer after the hyphen. If your file is in a sub-directory (templates/content-aside.php):

```
get_template_part( 'templates/content', 'aside' );
```

Is that what you're looking to do?

Comment: Thanks, I understand that. I'm looking to not have to create an index.php in the child theme to overwrite the parent themes index.php for a single line change. It adds more maintenance to the child theme. Hoping to accomplish via a hook if possible.