# how to remove get_template_part from a plugin?

Tags: get-template-part

I have a template file and that file has two `get_template_part()`.

ie,`get_template_part( 'store' );`

`get_template_part( 'header' );`

these two are used inside a template page,  I wanted here to remove these two `get_template_part()` from my plugin

ie, if I load a function from my plugin ,`get_template_part('store')` must not be shown.it should be removed from the template page.

can anyone please suggest some ways to do it.

Comment: There is no filter for `get_template_part()`, but what you want may be achieved by replacing the template itself from a custom plugin. [This answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/259307/110572) has some related details.

Comment: To be clear: The answer to that question requires that the original theme be changed. If you want your plugin to remove template parts from themes you don't control, *that's* not possible at all.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible. There just aren't any filters for filtering templates loaded with `get_template_part()` that you could use to achieve this.